# How can I have multiple files with custom function declarations?

Tags: excel, webpack, office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

I would like to split up Excel Custom Function declarations into multiple files for code cleanliness. I changed the webpack `entry.functions` into an array and added the two separate files:

```js
module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const buildType = dev ? "dev" : "prod";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      ...
      functions: ["./src/functions/one.ts", "./src/functions/two.ts"],
      ...
```

Then (also in webpack config) I added separate `CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin` entries in plugins for each of the files:

```js
...
plugins: [
      new CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin({
        output: "functions.json",
        input: "./src/functions/one.ts",
      }),
      new CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin({
        output: "functions.json",
        input: "./src/functions/two.ts",
      }),
...
```

It builds fine but running in Excel only the functions from the last `CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin` plugin entry are visible (in this case those custom functions declared in `two.ts`).

Is there a way to separate excel custom function declarations into multiple files?

Comment: It makes sense to check the `functions.json` content then? Do you see any difference if you build the single file without splitting the source code?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev When splitting, the generated `function.json` only contains the functions from the file  of the last CustomFunctionMetadataPlugin declared in webpack config. I'm wondering if there is a way to have it pull functions from multiple files and place them all in function.json. The [examples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts/blob/master/packages/custom-functions-metadata-plugin/README.md) from Microsoft only have one single file.

Comment: That is question to the webpack, not MS.

Comment: I've raised this [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts/issues/681) which is where this change would need to be made.